# I need to convert the levels of multiple categorical variable into 0,1

Tags: r

I have five columns with 2 levels and their column names are like `c(a,b,x,y,z)`. The command below works for 1 column at time. But I need to it for all five columns at the same time.

```
levels(car_data[,"x"]) <- c(0,1)
car_data[,"x"] <- as.numeric(levels(car_data[,"x"]))[car_data[,"x"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are two levels, then we can do

```
library(dplyr)
car_data %>%
        mutate_all(funs(as.integer(.)-1))
#  a b c 
#1 0 0 0
#2 1 1 1
#3 0 0 0
#4 1 1 1
```

#### data

```
car_data <- structure(list(a = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("a", 
"b"), class = "factor"), b = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("a", 
"b"), class = "factor"), c = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("a", 
"b"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("a", "b", "c"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```